How to efficiently clean unneeded channels/fcurves up before/after applying Pose Asset
If I create a new pose asset, every parameter on every selected(?) bone has a keyframe created in the new library.  This creates a large amount of channels/keys, even for transforms on locked parameters (e.g., a bone that has locked scales or position (FK bones)):


For almost all of my workflow (IK,FK bones), only location or rotation are needed, so creating or applying a pose creates a cumbersome "mess" that I want to keep clean.
Are there any scripts or add-ons that could help create a cleaner pose asset -- either during creation or after applying?
